# On the full likelihood of a transformed sample and the partial likelihood

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I am following the 1975 paper by Cox entitled *Partial Likelihood*.

Consider a vector $y$ of observations represented by a random variable $Y$ having density $f_Y(y;\theta)$ and suppose that $Y$ is transformed into the sequence $(X_1,S_1,X_2, S_2 \dots,X_m, S_m)$ then the full likelihood of this sequence is

$$\prod_{j=1}^m f_{X_j | X^{(j-1)} , S^{(j-1)}} (x_j| x^{(j-1),} s^{(j-1)}; \theta ) \prod_{j=1}^m f_{S_j | X^{(j)} , S^{(j-1)}} (s_j| x^{(j),} s^{(j-1)}; \theta )$$

- Are we transforming $Y$ into a sequence by, as an example, applying a
  function $f:R \rightarrow R^n$ to $Y$ or is it a different
  transformation?
- How is the full likelihood obtained? I tried repeated conditioning in the case $m=4$ but in Cox formula the marginal densities are conditioned only on the previous term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Are we transforming $Y$ into a sequence?
Not in the way you're implying by your function $f:R \rightarrow R^n$. Remember that $Y$ is a vector. Think of the transformation as simply being a way of decomposing, partitioning or rewriting $Y$.

Example 1 later in the paper makes this idea clearer. Here, Cox considers a discrete time discrete state stochastic process with a special state denoted $0$. In this case $Y$ would be a full description of the state occupied at each time point. Alternatively, we can rewrite $Y$ as $(X_1,S_1,X_2, S_2 \dots,X_m, S_m)$ where each $X_i$ describes the path of the process in between visits to state $0$, while $S_i$ counts the number of time steps spent at $0$ on the $i$'th visit. It's clear that the full description of the process can be recovered from the rewritten version.

Q2. How is the full likelihood obtained? Look **very** carefully at the notation below equation (2) in the paper and you'll see that e.g. $X^{(j)}:=(X_1, X_2,\dots,X_j)$ so the conditioning is not only on the previous term.

For example, in the case $m=4$, we get the full likelihood $f(x_4,s_4,x_3,s_3,x_2,s_2,x_1,s_1)$ as

$\eqalign{
 &=f(x_4,s_4,x_3,s_3,x_2,s_2 | x_1,s_1) f(x_1,s_1) \\
&= f(x_4,s_4,x_3,s_3,x_2,s_2 | x_1,s_1) f(s_1 | x_1) f(x_1)\\
&= f(x_4,s_4,x_3,s_3 | x_2,s_2,x_1,s_1) f(x_2,s_2 | x_1, s_1)f(s_1 | x_1) f(x_1)\\
&=f(x_4,s_4,x_3,s_3 | x_2,s_2,x_1,s_1) f(s_2 | x_2,x_1, s_1)f(x_2 | x_1,s_1)f(s_1 | x_1) f(x_1)\\
&=f(x_4,s_4 | x_3,s_3, x_2,s_2,x_1,s_1) f(x_3,s_3 | x_2,s_2,x_1,s_1) \times f(s_2 | x_2,x_1, s_1)f(x_2 | x_1,s_1)f(s_1 | x_1) f(x_1)
}$

You can see that, when you rewrite each of the first two terms above by conditioning (on $x_4$ and $x_3$ respectively), the resultant expression is equivalent to equation (2) in the paper in the case $m=4$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you please derive the likelihood in the case $m=4$?

Comment: @Monolite I've included most of the derivation now. Basically, it's repeated application of $P(AB|C)=P(A|BC)P(B|C)$.